# Boost multi index ordered iterators assignment

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index

I've got a boost multi_index_container storing a bunch of locations with the following index

```
boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<Slot>,
            boost::multi_index::identity<SlotData>
        >,  //ordered_unique
    boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<Level>,
            SlotData::ExtractZ
        >,  // ordered_non_unique
...//index by
.//typedef as SlotLocations
```

In this definition, I believe the default index will be by `ordered_unique` based on `Slot`. Later on I have an iterator `SlotLocations::iterator` that I want to use to store the result from a search based on `Level` which is `ordered_non_unique`:

```
typedef SlotLocations::index<Level>::iterator MIterator;

std::pair<MIterator, MIterator> range = map.get<Level>().range(..some conds..);

SlotLocations::iterator itr = range.first;    //error
```

The ranged search works and return the desired result stored in `range`, however this code won't compile with the lined marked giving the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator='
```

Why can't I assign/store the iterators like this? And what's the possible ways to store the search result iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to project the iterators across indices

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection

It should be like

```
 SlotLocations::iterator itr = project<Slot>(map, range.first);
```

Comment: Cheers, missed that. Why didn't boost implement automatic 'casting' for this?

Comment: @xmrflipflop I presume you mean implicit conversions? Well, for one thing, untagged indexes might have identical types (this is solvable iwht more TMP). More importantly though, implicit conversions tend to break up in more complex environments or lead to hard-to-diagnose surprises.

Answer (score 2):

As for your second question on why projection is not done automatically through implicit conversions: in fact the reason is *not* the one suggested by @sehe (all indices are different even if untagged, and their iterators are guaranteedly different types), but this: projection is done through an expression like

```
it1 =  c.project<X>(it0); // X is either a tag or an index number
```

which needs the user to provide *the container* both iterators belong to: that is, you cannot (in general) convert from `it0` to `it1` with the information held by `it0` alone.